# Prevent pointerdown event from triggering on mobile when user tapholds and scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, touch, mouseevent

Hello I have implemented a long press javascript event handler which is working perfectly fine. However, on mobile, users tap...hold... in order to scroll up or down. This scrolling interaction on mobile is unintentionally triggering my 'pointerdown' event. I've tried inserting a `pointermove` event in the chain of event handlers but that seems to trigger an arbitrary amount of times, depending on how long the user is moving their pointer while pointerdown, therefore I am unable to set a boolean that is reliable and doesn't flip back and forth.

```
let pressTimer;
this.myElements.on('pointerup', (e) => {
  clearTimeout(pressTimer);
}).on('pointerdown', (e) => {
  let myEl = $(e.currentTarget);
  let checkbox= myEl.find('.checkbox');
  pressTimer = window.setTimeout(() => {
    checkbox.click();
  }, 750)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a global boolean variable which holds the current status of the pointer (maybe **isPointerDown**) and act accordingly. e.g. if it's true don't react to pointerdown and if there's a pointerup event reset this variable to false.

```
let pressTimer;
var isPointerDown = false;
this.myElements.on('pointerup', (e) => {
  clearTimeout(pressTimer);
  isPointerDown = false;
}).on('pointerdown', (e) => {
  if (!isPointerDown) {
    let myEl = $(e.currentTarget);
    let checkbox = myEl.find('.checkbox');
    pressTimer = window.setTimeout(() => {
      isPointerDown = true;
      checkbox.click();
    }, 750)
  }
});
```

Comment: but wouldn't isPointerDown still be true for when user is scrolling up or down? thats what I'm trying to prevent. sorry maybe I wasn't clear

Comment: Inside the pointerdown handler we're checking the current value of isPointerDown - if it's true it won't call the setTimout and thus the click() on the checkbox after 750ms. Isn't this what you want to prevent?

Comment: i tried, didn't work. my guess is because scrolling also activates pointerdown

Comment: i solved the tapping while scroll issue by comparing window.scrollY values at the start and within the setTimeout of pointerdown

Comment: Nice! Glad you could find a solution.